# Different select sql in case statement

Tags: sql, select, case

I need to add blank rows to a sql result in order to have always 3 rows. If my query returns 0 rows I need to make 3 unions of a blank row, if the query returns 1 row, I need to UNION 2 blank rows. If the query returns 2 rows I need to UNION only one blank row, and if the query returns 3 rows, add no blanks rows.

I'm newbie to SQL and I was trying something like this:

```
SELECT CASE (COUNT(*) FROM public_getxo_alumbrado_puntos_luz_soportes_demo where id_punto_luz=CInt(Reports![TODO_horizontal]!id_punto_luz))
WHEN 0 THEN (SELECT * FROM public_getxo_alumbrado_puntos_luz_soportes_demo where id_punto_luz=CInt(Reports![TODO_horizontal]!id_punto_luz) 
UNION ALL Select DISTINCT '' as tipo_soporte , '' as subtipo_soporte, '' as soporte_ppal_forma, '' as material, '' as soporte_ppal_altura, '' as longitud, '' as soporte_aux_angulo, '' as modelo, '' as marca, '' as estado, '' as fecha_instalacion, '' as fecha_intervencion, '' as fecha_baja, '' as observaciones, '' as tipo_intervencion , CInt(Reports![TODO_horizontal]!id_punto_luz) as id_punto_luz, '' as id_soporte, '' as id_modelo  from public_getxo_alumbrado_puntos_luz_soportes_demo 
UNION ALL Select DISTINCT '' as tipo_soporte , '' as subtipo_soporte, '' as soporte_ppal_forma, '' as material, '' as soporte_ppal_altura, '' as longitud, '' as soporte_aux_angulo, '' as modelo, '' as marca, '' as estado, '' as fecha_instalacion, '' as fecha_intervencion, '' as fecha_baja, '' as observaciones, '' as tipo_intervencion , CInt(Reports![TODO_horizontal]!id_punto_luz) as id_punto_luz, '' as id_soporte, '' as id_modelo  from public_getxo_alumbrado_puntos_luz_soportes_demo 
UNION ALL Select DISTINCT '' as tipo_soporte , '' as subtipo_soporte, '' as soporte_ppal_forma, '' as material, '' as soporte_ppal_altura, '' as longitud, '' as soporte_aux_angulo, '' as modelo, '' as marca, '' as estado, '' as fecha_instalacion, '' as fecha_intervencion, '' as fecha_baja, '' as observaciones, '' as tipo_intervencion , CInt(Reports![TODO_horizontal]!id_punto_luz) as id_punto_luz, '' as id_soporte, '' as id_modelo  from public_getxo_alumbrado_puntos_luz_soportes_demo)

WHEN 1 THEN (SELECT * FROM public_getxo_alumbrado_puntos_luz_soportes_demo where id_punto_luz=CInt(Reports![TODO_horizontal]!id_punto_luz)
UNION ALL Select DISTINCT '' as tipo_soporte , '' as subtipo_soporte, '' as soporte_ppal_forma, '' as material, '' as soporte_ppal_altura, '' as longitud, '' as soporte_aux_angulo, '' as modelo, '' as marca, '' as estado, '' as fecha_instalacion, '' as fecha_intervencion, '' as fecha_baja, '' as observaciones, '' as tipo_intervencion , CInt(Reports![TODO_horizontal]!id_punto_luz) as id_punto_luz, '' as id_soporte, '' as id_modelo  from public_getxo_alumbrado_puntos_luz_soportes_demo
UNION ALL Select DISTINCT '' as tipo_soporte , '' as subtipo_soporte, '' as soporte_ppal_forma, '' as material, '' as soporte_ppal_altura, '' as longitud, '' as soporte_aux_angulo, '' as modelo, '' as marca, '' as estado, '' as fecha_instalacion, '' as fecha_intervencion, '' as fecha_baja, '' as observaciones, '' as tipo_intervencion , CInt(Reports![TODO_horizontal]!id_punto_luz) as id_punto_luz, '' as id_soporte, '' as id_modelo  from public_getxo_alumbrado_puntos_luz_soportes_demo)

WHEN 2 THEN (SELECT * FROM public_getxo_alumbrado_puntos_luz_soportes_demo where id_punto_luz=CInt(Reports![TODO_horizontal]!id_punto_luz)
UNION ALL Select DISTINCT '' as tipo_soporte , '' as subtipo_soporte, '' as soporte_ppal_forma, '' as material, '' as soporte_ppal_altura, '' as longitud, '' as soporte_aux_angulo, '' as modelo, '' as marca, '' as estado, '' as fecha_instalacion, '' as fecha_intervencion, '' as fecha_baja, '' as observaciones, '' as tipo_intervencion , CInt(Reports![TODO_horizontal]!id_punto_luz) as id_punto_luz, '' as id_soporte, '' as id_modelo  from public_getxo_alumbrado_puntos_luz_soportes_demo)

WHEN 3 THEN (SELECT * FROM public_getxo_alumbrado_puntos_luz_soportes_demo where id_punto_luz=CInt(Reports![TODO_horizontal]!id_punto_luz))
END
FROM public_getxo_alumbrado_puntos_luz_soportes_demo;
```

Comment: A non-binding advice: if possible, do such things outside of SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS precedence, * FROM FROM public_getxo_alumbrado_puntos_luz_soportes_demo where id_punto_luz=CInt(Reports![TODO_horizontal]!id_punto_luz
    UNION
    SELECT 2 AS precedence, '' as tipo_soporte , '' as subtipo_soporte, '' as soporte_ppal_forma, '' as material, '' as soporte_ppal_altura, '' as longitud, '' as soporte_aux_angulo, '' as modelo, '' as marca, '' as estado, '' as fecha_instalacion, '' as fecha_intervencion, '' as fecha_baja, '' as observaciones, '' as tipo_intervencion , CInt(Reports![TODO_horizontal]!id_punto_luz) as id_punto_luz, '' as id_soporte, '' as id_modelo  from public_getxo_alumbrado_puntos_luz_soportes_demo
    UNION 
    SELECT 3 AS precedence, '' as tipo_soporte , '' as subtipo_soporte, '' as soporte_ppal_forma, '' as material, '' as soporte_ppal_altura, '' as longitud, '' as soporte_aux_angulo, '' as modelo, '' as marca, '' as estado, '' as fecha_instalacion, '' as fecha_intervencion, '' as fecha_baja, '' as observaciones, '' as tipo_intervencion , CInt(Reports![TODO_horizontal]!id_punto_luz) as id_punto_luz, '' as id_soporte, '' as id_modelo  from public_getxo_alumbrado_puntos_luz_soportes_demo
    )
ORDER BY precedence
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Thanks worked for me in ms access using TOP 3 instead of LIMIT 3

Comment: You didn't say what database you're using. My answer works in MySQL.